# Custom hit-test area

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Stack with a background widget and a foreground widget with a certain transparent area.

Is it possible to implement a custom shaped IgnorePointer so that the said transparent area forwards pointer events to the background widget?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue by designing a Widget W where some other Widget V in W’s tree can be marked (GlobalKey) as “transparent to hit-test”.

In the hitTest of W, W checks if V would be hit. If yes it returns false and thus stops the hitTest which results in handling of the pointer by the Widget(s) behind V.

Basically, V punches a hole in the hitTest of W.

Answer (score -2):

I would think you would need to wrap the target widget in a GestureDetector and in the ontap property call the appropriate function.